# The CheckMarx security scanner gives error on Stored XSS vulnerability

Tags: visualforce, javascript, checkmarx, xss

I have a javaScript method in my visualforce page, which is adding a css when page loads.

Code adds the css to radio buttons to look similar to Lightning radio buttons.

```
    var Row = document.getElementsByClassName("convertToLSD");
    for (var k = 0; k < Row.length; k++) {
        var colTds = Row[k].getElementsByTagName("td");
        for (var i = 0; i < colTds.length; i++) {

            var inrHtml = colTds[i].innerHTML;

            var chkId = inrHtml.substring(inrHtml.indexOf("id=") + 4, inrHtml.indexOf("\"", inrHtml.indexOf("id=") + 4));
            var chkBx = inrHtml.substring(inrHtml.indexOf("<input"), inrHtml.indexOf(">") + 1);
            var chkLable = colTds[i].getElementsByTagName("label")[0].textContent;
            var typeOfInput = colTds[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].getAttribute("type");
            var newChkBox = '<label class="slds-' + typeOfInput + '" for="' + chkId + '">' + chkBx +
                '<span class="slds-' + typeOfInput + '--faux"></span>' +
                '<span class="slds-form-element__label">' + chkLable + '</span>' +
                '</label>';
            colTds[i].innerHTML = newChkBox;
        }
    }
```

I tried in my apex code with select options

```
options.add(new selectOption(u.Id,u.Name.escapehtml4()));
```

but this also didn't work.

Comment: The title of your question and the actual question itself seem to be different. Are you asking how to resolve the checkmarx issue, or is your css not working?

Comment: Hi @DerekF, I want to resolve the checkmarx issue.